# Is it possible to adapt width wx.StaticBox?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

i've made this code :

```
import wx
import List as li
from ChoiceBook import *

class MainTab(wx.Panel):
   def __init__(self, parent, sb, dm):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.hardware = []
    box = wx.StaticBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Appareil")
    self.list = li.List(self, sb, dm)
    sizerleft = wx.StaticBoxSizer(box,wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizerleft.Add(self.list, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)




    box = wx.StaticBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Mesures")
    self.notebook = Choicebook(self,dm)

    sizerright = wx.StaticBoxSizer(box,wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizerright.Add(self.notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)



    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer.Add(sizerleft, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    sizer.Add(sizerright, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)

   def update(self):
       self.notebook.update()
```

it made this [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNLGE.png), but when i resize it, it dosen't scale the contents. it just crop it, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF572.png).

I think the probleme come from the StaticBox which are static i guess(i'm not sure).

I would like to know if it's possible to make it resize automatically?

or if not is there is another way to make a box whith a title like StaticBox and so make it resizable ?

EDIT: i figure it out with your help. in fact this wasn't this portion of cod fault but my list Class. i just remove all size in that file 
before

```
wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self,
                         parent,
                         size=(800, -1),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)
    self.rm = RM.Res_Man()
    self.index = 0

    self.InsertColumn(0, 'Appareil de mesure', width=125)
    self.InsertColumn(1, 'Connecté')
    self.InsertColumn(2, 'ID',width=300)
    self.InsertColumn(3, 'Type',width=290)
    self.sb = sb
```

after

```
wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self,
                         parent,
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)
    self.rm = RM.Res_Man()
    self.index = 0

    self.InsertColumn(0, 'Appareil de mesure')
    self.InsertColumn(1, 'Connecté')
    self.InsertColumn(2, 'ID')
    self.InsertColumn(3, 'Type')
    self.sb = sb
```

thanks you all ;)

Comment: it is probably native system behavior. Can you try without wxStaticBox just for testing?

Comment: Sorry, it seems to me that the code you've posted doesn't match those images. Perhaps you want to post the real code. Appart from that, I don't see any issue with the sizers, all sub-windows should be resized by the same proportion.

Comment: Just for the reference: "static" means that it doesn't generate any events (unlike buttons, check boxes etc), it definitely does *not* mean that it can't change size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you want, is to force it to `Layout()` on a `RESIZE` event.
However, remember that these items will have a minimum size.

Try this:

```
import wx

class MainTab(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.hardware = []
        box = wx.StaticBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Appareil")
        lc = wx.ListCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL|wx.LC_VRULES)
        lc.InsertColumn(1, "Appareil de mesure")
        lc.InsertColumn(2, "Connecte")
        lc.InsertColumn(3, "ID")
        lc.InsertColumn(4, "Type")
        sizerleft = wx.StaticBoxSizer(box,wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizerleft.Add(lc, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        box = wx.StaticBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Mesures")
        cb = wx.Choicebook(self, wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize,
               style=0, name="")

        sizerright = wx.StaticBoxSizer(box,wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizerright.Add(cb, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(sizerleft, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(sizerright, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.ReSize)

    def ReSize(self,event):
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainTab()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I have had to hack it together as your code is in complete.